# Какую букву посоветуете для обозначения “ьы/йы”, буквы типа я, ю, е, ё?

Tags: алфавит, other-languages

я обнаружил, что в кириллице не хватает буквы - пары для ы, как я является парой для а.

в русском языке такой буквы не нужно, но вот в татарском, например, такая буква нужна: например, если к слову "лагерь" добавить суффикс ы, получится [л а г е рь ы], но написать это кириллицей никак. (вариант лагерьы не годится, так как ь является разделяющей буквой).

предложите варианты для буквы "ьы/йы". это может быть в виде рисунка, или составлено из знаков юникода.

я не спрашиваю у вас буквы для татарского языка, я спрашиваю букву для данной идеи, пары для ы, если бы такая буква была нужна в русском языке.

---

скопировано из закрытого вопроса из rus.stackexchange.com ( [№449943](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449943/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8C%D1%8B-%D0%B9%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D1%8F-%D1%8E-%D0%B5-%D1%91) , обсуждение на мете [№441](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5) ).

если бы я обратился в https://conlang.stackexchange.com/ , как предложил Aer♦, то, думаю, там же тоже наверно не специалисты по кириллице сидят, и они сами обратились бы куда-нибудь как этот сайт.

также в защиту "легальности" вопроса хочу сказать, мне кажется, письменность на основе кириллицы для языков ссср и советского блока создавалась на основе русской письменности.

этот вопрос "open ended", то есть, может получать неограниченно много разных ответов, но хороших, приемлемых, удобных решений, должно быть, не очень много.

Comment: Какими критериями мы должны руководствоваться при выборе этой буквы?

Comment: При необходимости передачи такого звука в русском используется сочетание йы, как, например, в названии эстонского города Йыхви.

Comment: Такой пары нет и для буквы <и>. Могу предложить для вашей цели использовать букву <ы> с двоеточием (с умлаутом) над ней: [Ӹӹ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ӹ), тем более, чио такая буква имеется в Юникоде.

Comment: Just open a unicode symbol map and choose whatever letter you'll like: ы, ыۣ , ыۚ, љ, њ, џ, ₪, ۵ۣ.

Comment: Это не вопрос про русский язык

Answer (score 1):

Всё же мы здесь обсуждаем русский язык, а не все варианты существования кириллицы. Как показывает опыт, для сообществ носителей разных языков не составляет проблемы добавить недостающую букву, как ў, ұ, ң и так далее. Поэтому мой ответ - такая буква могла бы выглядеть как угодно, хоть ы с краткой. Это зависит исключительно от мнения лингвистов, разрабатывающих нормы письменности для данного народа, представителей этого народа.